# Wordpress Menu Displaying with page url

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the blank HTML5 theme and everything was working well until I updated some plugins and now every menu in the site renders with the page url.

Here is how every menu is rendering.

> Articles http://localhost:8085/mysite/?page_id=101
>
> Home http://localhost:8085/mysite/?page_id=102

Here is the menu code from **function.php**

```
// HTML5 Blank navigation
function html5blank_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
}
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: nobody outside your computer can see your localhost.

Comment: First step: Share the menu code with us.

Comment: Those links are not for you to access my localhost its just how the whole menu is rendering.The only thing i can send you is **the functions** file because it has the menu code. and

Comment: paste menu code from function.php

Comment: I believe it's more a Wordpress question than PHP question since the problem started when you've updated some plugins. Consider disabling all of your plugins and check if it's working. After that, activate them one by one until you'll find the plugin that conflicts with your theme.

Comment: @AshPatel that's the code for the menus'

Answer (score 0):

Go to->setting->permalink
Here you have to select "Post name" and click on the save button then refresh your website.

Comment: naranawal the problem is not how my links display

Answer (score 0):

in header.php file call this function for display menu.

like :

```
if(function_exists('html5blank_nav')):
                wp_nav_menu( 
                    array( 
                        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                        'menu'            => '',
                        'container'       => 'div',
                        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
                        'container_id'    => '',
                        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
                        'menu_id'         => '',
                        'echo'            => true,
                        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                        'before'          => '',
                        'after'           => '',
                        'link_before'     => '',
                        'link_after'      => '',
                        'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
                        'depth'           => 0,
                        'walker'          => ''
                        )  
                    );
```